# Problema ao passar os dados do banco para TextView android

Tags: android

Não estou conseguindo exibir dados do banco para o TextView.

BD

```
public MessageEB buscarConfiguracoes() {

    String[] colunas = new String[]{"data"};

    Cursor cursor = bd.query("dados", colunas, null, null, null, null, null);

    MessageEB messageEB = new MessageEB();

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        messageEB.setData(cursor.getString(0));
    }

    cursor.close();

    return messageEB;
}
```

Fragment Enviar

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("LOG", "FragmentEnviar.this.onClick()");

        MessageEB m = new MessageEB();
        m.setClassTester(FragmentExibir.class+"");
        m.setData(editar.getText().toString());

        EventBus.getDefault().post(m);

        dados.setData(editar.getText().toString());
        BD bd = new BD(getActivity());
        bd.atualizar(dados);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data alterada com sucesso! " + dados.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Fragment Exibir

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exibir, container, false);

        EventBus.getDefault().register(FragmentExibir.this);


    txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.campoData2);


    BD bd = new BD(getActivity());
    txt.setText(bd.buscarConfiguracoes().getData());

    return view;
}
```

Dados é o nome da tabela do banco.
Quando eu chamo o dado do banco, ele não é exibido.

Comment: O que exatamente não está dando certo? Não está conseguindo buscar no banco? Se busca, o que acontece depois que não está satisfazendo sua necessidade?

Comment: Quando eu chamo o dado do banco com a função [BD bd = new BD(getActivity());txt.setText(bd.buscarConfiguracoes().getData());] não aparece nada.

Comment: Este é o tipo de coisa que é preciso *debugar*. Por exemplo, você consegue verificar se `cursor.getString(0)` na sua classe `DB` retorna algum valor no *console* (pode utilizar `Log.i()`)? Se não estiver, tem certeza que seu método de `atualizar()` de fato está gravando os dados no banco?

Comment: Como eu colocaria esse log de informação para fazer essa análise?

Comment: Com esse código que eu uso para exibir o valor no TextView, o TextView que tem coisas escritas, some. Ele fica sempre apagado.

Comment: Aparece esse erro: A SQLiteConnection object for database  was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: Utilize `Log.i("a", cursor.getString(0))` ou se estiver mais fácil, use as funções de *debug* da própria IDE. Isso é só para ver se realmente existe o valor esperado no banco de dados. No seu método `buscarConfiguracoes()`, você precisa dar um `close()` também no objeto **db** depois que utiliza-lo.

Comment: Deu um probleminha aqui. Agora vou testar suas dicas.

Comment: Esse log não é exibido no debug

Comment: Isso pode estar acontecendo por que aos dois fragments estão se comunicando por EventBus?

Comment: Não sei o que esse *EventBus* faz, acredito que não tem relação. Mas se não está exibindo, talvez nem esteja realmente salvando. Então é preciso validar isso no seu método `atualizar()`.

Comment: Sim, acredito que esse pode ser o problema. Preciso analisar o problema, mas já vi tanto esse código, não sei onde pode estar o erro. O EventBus faz comunicação entre fragments.